# Understanding Measures and Filters Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Suppose I have a table Tb comprised of only one column A with values {a, a, a, b, b, c}. Suppose further that I have a slicer for this attribute. If I define a measure M = CALCULATE(COUNT(Tb[values]), Tb[values] = "a"). Then, if I select b from the slicer, the measure shows the value 3. Shouldn't it be 0 or blank? If I further define a new column B, say {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1} and create a slicer S for this column, then if I select 1, the result of M is 2, as it should be. Is it a bug, or a feature? Why does this happen?

Sorry for the bad formatting, I am new to SO and I actually don't know how to write a nice question, but I believe it is quite understandable.

I tried using allselected, and editing the interactions of the slicers, in order to achieve the expected result. This was in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single column Table with values a, b.
Give relationship one to many from this new table to original table.
Use column from new table in slicer.
Then slicer works correctly.

[image]

Comment: It did solve my problem. Can I ask you why does it work?